# Retrieve data contained a certain span class

Tags: php

using `file_get_contents`, I open an Internet URL and get the contents of this webpage.

Inside the HTML there are many identical span class tags:

```
<span class="always-the-same-class">always dynamic text</span>
```

Now, I want to get an array containing all the "dynamic text" contained in any of this tags. It is not necessary to eliminate duplicated entries (I need them).

Is this possible? How could I do?

Comment: Based in the fact you want to work with html components, I can't see a use for PHP, only JavaScript. Use jQuery .each() function, it will help, and then you send this information to php

Comment: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ here you will find all such problems with solutions..

Comment: @Euger Rieck: isn't preg_match to find all occurrencies of a given string? If so, I don't need only this: I need to find the text after that string too.

Comment: @Gerep: JavaScript is not useful in my context: the page is opened by a cronjob+curl and the browser never gets opened.

Comment: Please, add that information on your question ;)

Comment: @RajatSinghal: this is interesting.

Comment: @Gerep: I asked a PHP question!   :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this has to be PHP as it is on the server, not in the browser. So I'd do something like

```
$html=file_get_contents(HTML_URL);
$a=preg_match_all("/\<span class\=\"always-the-same-class\"\>(.*?)\<\/span\>/",$html,$b);
echo $a;
print_r($b[1]);
```

$a has hit count, $b[1] the hits

Tested this against

```
<html>
.. blah ..
<body>

.. blah ..

<span class="always-the-same-class">always dynamic text A</span>
<span class="always-the-same-class">always dynamic text B</span>
<span class="always-the-same-class">always dynamic text C</span>

.. blah ..

</body>
</html>
```

and output was

```
3
Array
(
    [0] => always dynamic text A
    [1] => always dynamic text B
    [2] => always dynamic text C
)
```

Comment: Little problem noticed just now: in that webpage, they sometimes use 'always-the-same-class', some other times "always-the-same-class".

Comment: In this case you would adapt the regex to /\<span class\=\"always[ -]the[ -]same[ -]class\"\>(.*?)\<\/span\>/

Comment: the difference is in the "" and ''

Comment: Sorry, in your first version it was blanks against dashes ... so you'd use /\<span class\=['\"]always-the-same-class['\"]\>(.*?)\<\/span\>/

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why I get `0Array ( )`

Comment: have you replaced HTML_URL by your URL?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6529/discussion-between-ele3000-and-eugen-rieck)

Answer (score 0):

jquery:

```
var spanText = $('.always-the-same-class').text();
```

Comment: I don't need JQuery and JavaScript! I posted a PHP question!

Comment: I see 2 ways, 1: a preg_match 2: do function that will run the jquery function and that will return it's value and than you grab it and store it in a variable :), all of this inside php

Comment: JavaScript is not useful in my context: the page is opened by a cronjob+curl and the browser never gets opened

Comment: Useful or not, trust me... it would do its thing, and I am saying this because I did it. But anyways, I do prefer @Eugen Rieck's answer

Comment: @wOrldart: the browser is not opened, I can't change my context, there's simply no client side, please accept it  :-D

Comment: oh lol, you are right... now I have realized the no browser... damn it these long nights :D

Answer (score 0):

You can parse this content using the DOMDocument class that is provided in PHP. Once you load the content into the dom document you can then filter out the span tags by using
`$content->getElementsByTagName('span');`
Once you have done this then you can filter the results by the tags attributes and get the content.

Comment: No problem if the HTML is not well formed?