# php code to fetch <span> data

Tags: php, html

```
<span id="abc">MY_Data</span>
```

I want "MY_Data" as value in a php variable
Any help will be greatly appretiated
Note this value"MY_Data" is dynamic as it is generated through javascript function
Thanks in Advance
Swapnil

Comment: PHP is server side, so it can't directly read dynamic javascript entered text, you could post the contents to a php file with ajax maybe and store it in a session, just an idea

Answer (score 0):

PHP cannot read html elements. But there are many ways to send data to your php page. Use JavaScript for this ; or if you are using a form, store this value in a hidden field like this :

```
<input type="hidden" value="MY_Data" name="abc" />
```

If you do not have a form, but a link, you could also add a parameter to your url, like

```
<a href="page.php?abc=MY_Data">link</a>
```

and then retrieve it with `$_GET['abc']`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779682/retrieve-data-contained-a-certain-span-class this link might give u an idea as i was unable to understand the code

Comment: @Swapnil That can't be applied in your case since you said that the `span` content is generated by JavaScript, which runs on the visitors' browser, which is long after all PHP processes are complete.