# Extract string from match

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I am new to php and trying to extract data from url using preg_match_all

Problem is the matches are converted to strings and I cannot extract them individually

`<?php`
`$pattern = '/<span class="product".*/i';`
`$string = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');`

`preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);`
`echo '<b>preg_match_all()</b>';`
`echo '<pre>';`
`echo '<br /><b>Products:</b> ', var_dump($matches);`
`echo '</pre>';`

Returns

```
preg_match_all()

Products: array(1) {
  [0]=> array(7) {
      [0] => string(46) "Product 1"
      [1] => string(42) "Product 2"
      [2] => string(46) "Product 3"
      [3] => string(41) "Product 4"
      [4] => string(58) "Product 5"
      [5] => string(42) "Product 6"
      [6] => string(37) "Product 7"
  }
}
```

I am trying to extract 1 item at a time (i.e. separate elements) and place each into own variable if possible. Example: $product1 = "Product 1"

If I try `echo $matches[2];` to get Product 3 I get an undefined offset error

**EDIT:**

With help from this thread: [Retrieve data contained a certain span class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779682/retrieve-data-contained-a-certain-span-class)

Solution:

`<?php`
`$html=file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');`
`preg_match_all("/\<span class\=\"products\"\>(.*?)\<\/span\>/",$html,$b);`

`foreach($b as $key => $value) {`
`$$key = $value;`
`}`

`echo $value[4]; // Returns 4th key, or "Product 5"`

Yes I am terrible at formatting code

Comment: dont use regular expressions to parse html

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: You don't `(capture)` anything in your regex.

Comment: If you had provided an example of what you were trying to parse and the ouput you were looking to extract then maybe we would be able to work out what you need your regex to do - fir now, it's simply wrong.

Comment: Did you not read symcbean? Please read last sentence.

Comment: As the code reads it works fine. I just want to be able to retrieve specific elements of the $matches output.

Comment: @TomSaget If you paste some sample `span`s here, I'll show you how to extract data from them :) So paste some raw markup you plan to parse. I want to reach 1000 points today ;)

Comment: @CodeAngry, ok here is similar example. `<span class="Products-Name">Used Gibson USA</span><br />
                <span class="Products-Discription">Les Test Test Test Paul Custom 1986<br />
                    with Factory Kahler </span>` If I use `<span class="Products-Name"` in my RegEx it will extract "Used Gibson USA" as desired. However, because there are multiple "Products-Name" matches throughout the page, it will place them together in $matches. YES, I want to retrieve all matches for the <span class, but I want to extract each individually, i.e. separate into variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
$markup = '<span class="Products-Name">Used Gibson USA</span>
    <span class="Products-Discription">Les Test Test Test Paul Custom 1986
    <br />with Factory Kahler </span>';
$markup = preg_replace('~<br\\s*/?>~si', ' ', $markup); // replace <br> with space
$markup = preg_replace('~\\s+~', ' ', $markup); // compact consecutive spaces into a single space
if(preg_match_all('~<span class="Products-(.+?)">(.*?)</span>~si', $markup, $matches)){
    // trim the enite deep array
    array_walk_recursive($matches, function(&$match){
        $match = trim($match);
    });
    // this shows you how the $matches is structured
    list($raw_matches, $class_matches, $inner_matches) = $matches;
    // combine class names with span inner value
    var_dump(array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]));
}
// this is how you loop preg_match_all() results
foreach($matches[0] as $key => $raw_match){
    $class_match = $matches[1][$key];
    $inner_match = $matches[2][$key];
    if(!strcasecmp($class_match, 'what YOU seek')){
        echo $inner_match;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the result is basically identical to my original RegEx. Maybe I am mis-communicating

Comment: @TomSaget Did you try it? It does not look like yours at all.

Comment: I am basically trying to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779682/retrieve-data-contained-a-certain-span-class

Comment: I am trying to assign a key to a variable, so using his example of output I would assign key `0` in the array to `$new1`, which would equal `always dynamic text A`, etc

Comment: @TomSaget Added some more code to show you how to loop `preg_match_all` results.

Comment: I figured it out! Will post solution. Thanks